# Swift - Access controller from delegate

Tags: swift

Let's say I create a custom delegate for example for an UITextField creating a class and implementing the UITextFieldDelegate, and I want to update other elements, for instance a UILabel which is in the controller.
Is there any possibility to do this?
What is your best approach to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is to assign the view controller as the delegate of the UITextField. If you insist on using a special class, create a property in it in which you store the view controller. You can then perform 'callbacks' from the delegate to the view controller.

Comment: Yeah I adopted the solution with the actually ViewController temporarily, but I was thinking about reusability of the code.

Comment: Also thought about implementing the class with an UIViewController as a parameter for the init, so do You agree that's a good solution?

Comment: That could be a good solution if you're using the delegate from other view controllers as well. If you're not, just go for my solution. IMHO, the only code worth reusing in a UITextFieldDelegate is inside the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method - if you're using a lot of code here, you could 'outsource' it to a separate class or function.

Comment: If you want a reusable text field component, create a delegate that has an @IBCollection array property. This will allow you to add any number of views to the collection, and your delegate implementation can modify all of them when your text changes.